# How to copy data from gsheet to yaml using Python?

Tags: python, yaml, dump, gspread, pyyaml

could you please help? I have a task to copy metrics from google sheet to yaml file(one row = one metric = can be one separate yaml file).
I found out I can use gspread to read data from gsheet and PyYAML yaml.dump to create the yaml file. What I cant find out is actually how can I do that? How to make a list or dictionary so the yaml file will be created? How to make it to recognize column names and then go through rows(should I make two separate dictionaries? ). I have no experience with something like this so I am little bit lost:).

Example excel row - using | as delimiter

```
Metric group|   Metric |    Official business definition |  Preliminary simplistic |description |   Official team ownership (department - tribe)|   Proposed ownership (department - tribe) |   Team lead / Analytics lead |    Slack channel | Last update (person) |  Last update (date) |    Metric versions Dimensionality |    Data source (DB) |  Looker Data model availability |    Looker Data model name| Source of truth |   Target / Threshold |    Slack channel for notifications |Trading impact |Trading impact - quantified|   Useful links
```

My code so far

```
import gspread
import PyYAML

#service_account authorization
gc = gspread.service_account()

#add here google sheet url/id or name
sh = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/MYSPREADSHIT')

#test worksheet_list
#worksheet_list = sh.worksheets()

#test reading
print(sh.worksheet("Product/Business metrics v2").get('B3'))
```

Comment: Hi, one could probably come up with a solution for you that will be very close to what you need but I believe with a bit of time you can reach it yourself. I'll advise you start training using gspread with basic examples, basic needs. Split you problem in smaller problems then try to solve each one by one. You'll end up with 80% or 90% of the solution.

Comment: Thank you, you were right, with a little help I could achieve a lot:D. But unfortunately I got stuck on one thing, if you would want to check it here is the link for my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72481313/generate-yaml-file-per-unique-row-using-python