# Generate yaml file per unique row using python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, yaml, pyyaml

I am struggling with dumping to yaml data from dataframe and based on every row create separate yaml file that contains the id name from the original file. It is a copy job from google sheet using gspread and then outputting it to csv, creating the df and dict to map columns to yaml keys.
I struggle with the logic to generate yaml file for each metric.
When I run my code separate files are created but they contain garbage and not even data related to that exact metric id. Could you please help?

This is my code:

```
import gspread
import pandas as pd
import yaml

#service_account authorization
gc = gspread.service_account()

#add here google sheet url/id or name
sh = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/myspreadhsheet_with_metrics')

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(sh.worksheet('Product/Business metrics v2').get_values())

dataframe.to_csv("out.csv")

df = pd.read_csv("out.csv", header = 3)

df = df.drop('2', "columns")

df['Trading impact'] = df['Trading impact'].astype(str)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    metrics = [
       {'id': row['Metric'].replace(' ', '_').lower(),
        'type': 'custom',
        'database_id': 'baobab_00894976',
        'schedule': 'hourly',
        'sql': '',
        'display_name': row['Metric'].replace(' ', '_').lower(),
        'definition': row['Official business definition'],
        'description': row['Preliminary simplistic description'],
        'owner': row['Official team ownership (department - tribe)'],
        'team_lead': row['Team lead / Analytics lead'],
        'slack_channel': row['Slack channel'],
        'metric_versions': row['Metric versions'],
        'dimensionality': row['Dimensionality'],
        'data_source': row['Data source (DB)'],
        'looker_available': row['Looker Data model availability'],
        'looker_model': row['Looker Data model name'],
        'source_of_truth': row['Source of truth'],
        'threshold_type': 'gt',
        'threshold_value': row['Target / Threshold'],
        'trading_impact': row['Trading impact'] if row['Trading impact'] != 'nan' else 'not filled'
        }
       for i, row in df.iterrows()
        ]
    with open(metrics[i]["id"]+".yaml", "w") as o:
        yaml.dump(metrics, o)
```

Comment: Why the nested loop?

Comment: I didnt know how to do that better :/ ( I am a very beginner so basically I try everything and hope it would work).

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
        metrics = {
                'id': row['Metric'].replace(' ', '_').lower(),
                'type': 'custom',
                'database_id': 'baobab_00894976',
                'schedule': 'hourly',
                'sql': '',
                'display_name': row['Metric'].replace(' ', '_').lower(),
                'definition': row['Official business definition'],
                'description': row['Preliminary simplistic description'],
                'owner': row['Official team ownership (department - tribe)'],
                'team_lead': row['Team lead / Analytics lead'],
                'slack_channel': row['Slack channel'],
                'metric_versions': row['Metric versions'],
                'dimensionality': row['Dimensionality'],
                'data_source': row['Data source (DB)'],
                'looker_available': row['Looker Data model availability'],
                'looker_model': row['Looker Data model name'],
                'source_of_truth': row['Source of truth'],
                'threshold_type': 'gt',
                'threshold_value': row['Target / Threshold'],
                'trading_impact': row['Trading impact'] if row['Trading impact'] != 'nan' else 'not filled'
        }
    
        with open(metrics["id"]+".yaml", "w") as o:
            yaml.dump(metrics, o, sort_keys= False)
```